# BadRequest when PUT JSON data on Firebase REST API

Tags: c#, asp.net, firebase-realtime-database, restsharp

I have this code that I am using to PUT my JSON string on Firebase database:

```
RestRequest request = new RestRequest("MemberAndChannels/{userId}/{channelId}.json", Method.POST);

request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
request.AddParameter("auth", accessKey);
request.AddUrlSegment("userId", user.UUID);
request.AddUrlSegment("channelId", channel.UUID);
request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");

request.AddJsonBody(channelJson);

IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);

if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
{

} 
else {

}
```

But I am getting following error (StatusCode: BadRequest):

```
"{\n  \"error\" : \"Invalid data; couldn't parse JSON object, array, or value.\"\n}\n"
```

I've tried PUTing same data using curl and it worked. Can't figure out where I am doing wrong.

Comment: What is `channelJson`?

Comment: Your request has some error. Whether the channelJson is String or Json Object.?

Comment: channelJson is a Json object in String format. That's how I got channelJson:

var channelJson = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(channel);

Here channel is an object of a Class.

Comment: Can you print the channelJson value in console and check whether the request is prepared correctly?

Comment: Here's the value of channelJason:

{\"ChannelName\":\"Best\",\"ChannelImageUrl\":\"https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/chat-demo-25252.appspot.com/o/ProfileImages%2FAB5307D8-9AE9-40A3-8358-39F2AF8A62BA.png?alt=media\\u0026token=3q11ac21-7414-6562-85b4-111ffdda0047\",\"UUID\":\"24C9955C-AC97-4741-2314-5E950712A826\"}

Comment: Can you test it manually by passing this request in Postman? and Meanwhile, try with newtonsoft json . Change the channelJson  as  var channelJson =JsonConvert.SerializeObject(channel);

Comment: I have tried passing this request with curl and it worked fine. The values did gets updated in Firebase Database.

Comment: Oh. then add the request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");.

Comment: Still same error. :(

Comment: Oh. I have modified the code with slight changes . Please try with the below answer

Answer (score 0):

The object is being serialized twice (double serialized).

Pass the `channel` object as it is to `AddJsonBody` and the `request` will serialize it to JSON before sending body

```
request.AddJsonBody(channel);
```

assuming here `channel` is an object of a Class

Comment: Thank for your Answer. But error is still there and same.

Answer (score 0):

I have modified the code with slight changes. Please try with this

```
RestRequest request = new RestRequest("MemberAndChannels/{userId}/{channelId}.json", Method.POST);
request.AddParameter("auth", accessKey); // or request.AddHeader("auth", accessKey);
request.AddUrlSegment("userId", user.UUID);
request.AddUrlSegment("channelId", channel.UUID);

request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");
request.AddParameter("application/json", channelJson, ParameterType.RequestBody);

IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);

if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
{

} 
else {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

I soved it changing this code:

```
request.AddParameter("auth", accessKey);
```

by

```
request.AddQueryParameter("auth", accessKey);
```

I hope help you.

Regards

Comment: Add Parameter will be treated as AddQueryParameter in case of Get Request. However, you can check by changing as AddQueryParameter .